# Kinesis Spark streaming does read records: running in standalone cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have spark streaming application in java which read records from kineses stream (1 shard) and do some processing after that.

When I am running my application in spark local mode its able to receive records but when I run same application in standalone cluster its does not read records from kinesis stream.

I have used spark-submit command to run the application:

**Local mode:**

```
spark-submit --class com.test.Main --master local[3] --jars /test/test-saprk-app.jar
```

**Standalone cluster mode:** 
`spark-submit --class com.test.Main --master spark://<machine-ip>:7077 --deploy-mode cluster  --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 10GB --jars /test/test-saprk-app.jar`

*Spark version used: 2.4.0*

Could anyone please suggest what I am missing here ?

Comment: Hi @Anshu, did you check the logs so far? Do you get any error?

Comment: it was not throwing any error so I could not figure out what is missing.
Earlier I was running in local mode using a script which used to set accessKey and secretKey values.

For standalone mode also I was using similar script but those setting was not working for me. After moving that setting to spark-env.sh file it worked.

Comment: Perfect @AnshuGoel

Answer (score 1):

For reading data from kinesis we need to set accessKey and secretKey as env variables or IAM role if its a aws ec2 machine.

If spark application is submitted in cluster/client mode make sure that these properties are set else it wont read any data from kinesis stream as required credentials are missing.

I tried putting these env variables in conf/spark-env.sh file and it worked on every node of cluster